# Are joins possible in LDAP queries?

Tags: java, ldap

I've been doing some simple queries and so far things work. However, I would like to do a join between two objects. Does LDAP support joins like SQL does? How would an example join look like in a query? Do I have to execute multiple queries instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [UnboundID Directory Server](https://www.unboundid.com/products/identity-data-store.php) and the  commercial edition of the [LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/) supports the `JoinRequestControl`, which provides functionality very much like a SQL join. Other than that, there is no support for a standardized JOIN in the LDAP specifications.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Terry! And thanks for all those LDAP examples on Google Code!

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent functionality you're looking for in LDAP is achieved using the Deref control. It is not called a JOIN.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-masarati-ldap-deref-00

As noted here https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/ldapext/current/msg02210.html it is implemented in at least OpenLDAP and 389DS so it is already multi-vendor, with multi-implementation interoperability.

Comment: Does it have an OID by now?

Comment: It could not interoperate between OpenLDAP and 389DS if it did not.

Comment: So, err, what is it?

Comment: Use the source, Luke. That's what open source is about.

#define LDAP_CONTROL_X_DEREF            "1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.5.16"

Comment: I don't have the source, Luke, and I do really feel you could have provided that in answer to my first question. Thanks for the information.

Comment: There is no such thing as "I don't have the source." It's more authoritative than the low quality "information" that passes for answers around here.

[source](http://www.openldap.org/devel/gitweb.cgi?p=openldap.git;a=blob;f=include/ldap.h;h=4caacb15b3aa1a7152bb3fa08b483483f17ca625;hb=HEAD#l321)

Comment: OK, so when I use the source and consult the draft RFC I find the following: 'This LDAP extension is currently implemented in OpenLDAP software *using the temporary OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.5.16 under OpenLDAP's experimental OID arc.*' That's not the same thing as 'implemented in OpenLDAP', which is the 'low quality information' purveyed in your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as an answer, despite having accepted Terry's one, just for future references.

After doing some more research on the topic, I came across [this excellent article](http://mysqldump.azundris.com/archives/74-LDAP-is-not-relational.html) explaining why LDAP could not and should not be used for joins and why LDAP is not relational like a proper RDBMS.

Comment: That article is garbage, every point made in it is incorrect and was thoroughly disproved in comment #1 http://mysqldump.azundris.com/archives/74-LDAP-is-not-relational.html#c2185