# Query LDAP to get Role of a User

Tags: ldap, openldap, rbac

I am new to LDAP and I have tried implementing RBAC on OpenLDAP. I created some users (inetOrganizationPerson) and put them in groups (groupOfNames). Next I created some roles (organizationalRole) and associated (roleOccupant) them with user groups, instead of directly associating them with users.

[My Example Organization Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mywwk.png)

I am trying to write a query that can give me role of a given user. It should determine to which group or groups that user belongs to and what are the roles that are assigned to those groups.

I suppose I can do it through two separate queries:

1) /usr/local/bin/ldapsearch -x -b 'ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com' -s sub -LLL "(&(objectclass=groupOfNames)(member=uid=anurag,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com))" cn

2)/usr/local/bin/ldapsearch -x -b 'ou=Roles,dc=example,dc=com' -s sub -LLL "(&(objectclass=organizationalRole)(roleOccupant=cn=Administrators,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com))" cn

In the first query, member 'anurag' is the parameter and it yields 'Administrators' as the group to which user 'anurag' belongs to.
The second query takes 'Administrators' (from first query) as a parameter and it yields 'Admin' as the role.

**However I am looking for, how I can achieve this through a single query, provided it is more efficient? More importantly, how it is typically done?**

Comment: You are trying to query using what in the relational database world is called a "join". Most LDAP servers do not support joins. However, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811348/are-joins-possible-in-ldap-queries

Comment: All of the information in rlandster's link is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LDAP what you're looking for is accomplished using the Deref control.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-masarati-ldap-deref-00

Comment: It's a very useful extension. Somehow I wasn't aware of it. I wonder if there any servers except OpenLDAP that support it.

Comment: 389DS also implements it.

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative if you use Java would be to use http://directory.apache.org/fortress/, which is a full RBAC implementation that works on OpenLDAP.