# Attempting to sort out Manager Name from Get-ADUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Hello I'm currently trying to have my Get-ADUser expression to sort the Manager to just display the managers name. I have search for multiple solutions however nothing that matches what I've been trying to do with have all my properties listed as shown.

```
Get-ADUser $username  -Properties Enabled,employeeNumber,DisplayName,Mail,Description,office,extensionAttribute1,manager,AccountExpirationDate | 
    Select-Object Enabled, 
    @{Expression={$_.DisplayName};Label='Display Name';},
    @{Expression={$_.Mail};Label='Email';}, 
    @{Expression={$_.employeeNumber};Label='Employee Number'},
    @{Expression={$_.AccountExpirationDate};Label='Account Expiration Date'},
    @{Expression={$_.Description};Label='Account Description'}, 
    Office,
    @{Expression={$_.extensionAttribute1};Label='Cost Center';},
    Manager
    Format-list
```

Currently the output is:

```
Manager: CN=Billy Bob Manager,OU=Users,OU=MAHRS,OU=Locations,OU=Test,DC=corp,DC=TestDC,DC=com
```

I would like to know how I could keep everything under the original Get-ADUser.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `@{Expression={if(![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Manager)){(Get-ADUser -Identity $_.Manager).Name} else {$null}};Label='Manager'}`.

Comment: @Theo there is no need to check for nullability in `Select-Object` expressions since any terminating error is consumed by the expression and represented as null already: `'' | Select-Object @{ N='foo'; E={ throw }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 simple options, either query AD for the Manager's `.Name` attribute:

```bash
@{ Expression = { (Get-ADUser $_.Manager).Name }; Label = 'Manager' }
```

Or extract the `cn` from the DistinguishedName with regex:

```
@{ Expression = { $_.Manager -replace '^CN=|(?<!\\),.+' }; Label = 'Manager' }
```

Comment: `CN` is not `displayName`.  In most environments they are pretty close, though.  Things like user renames, honorifics, and site-specific policies can cause them to differ.

Comment: @Mitch they're asking for "the managers name" not their displayName tho

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Are you thinking they are asking for the manager's CN?  That would be a somewhat unusual request, made all the more unusual by the fact that the query is identifying the subordinate by `displayName` - not their CN.

Comment: @Mitch you should ask OP that question not me. If OP says they want to extract "the managers name", I will show them how to extract the `Name` AD Attribute which is what my answer is showing. I will not guess that their need was to extract their `displayName`, much different AD attribute.

Comment: I did not say that your answer was wrong, I did not downvote your answer, I merely pointed out that your answer produces the CN, not the display name - and that those were not equivalent.  This comment stems from the number of bugs I've received where CN was used accidentally in place of the far more commonly requested `displayName`.

Comment: @Mitch I understood your comment but I'm saying that OP asked for Name and Name is the objects common name. If what they actually wanted was the display name instead of name then I'll expect OPs feedback. I don't like to assume things

Comment: Sorry for the long wait on the reply, didn't expect to hear back so soon. I ended up going with extracting the CN from DistinguishedName as I did not want to query AD again after the first time around. Thank you for the answer as it worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible with Active Directory to do a "join" in a single LDAP query.  It is possible with other LDAP directories ([OpenLDAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811348/are-joins-possible-in-ldap-queries)) using the [dereference control](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-masarati-ldap-deref-00).

Comment: There are no LDAP queries in the question (irrespective of whether ones may be involved as an implementation detail _behind the scenes_), so your answer is confusing. By contrast, PowerShell's [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties), as shown in the question, allow arbitrary _nested_ `Get-ADUser` calls to be performed to achieve the desired result (though possibly inefficiently), as shown in Santiago's answer.

Comment: @mklement0, I agree that the original question may be asking whether the secondary lookup can be done in the same pipeline. This answer was in response to the askers request to keep things “under the original `Get-ADUser`”  - which I took to mean “in a single call to `Get-ADUser`”.

Comment: I agree that the question is ambiguous in that respect, yet, even with your (debatable) interpretation that the intent is to avoid nested `Get-ADUser` calls (for which Santiago's answer also offers a solution, within the constraints you noted), your answer is still obscure in its current form.

Comment: @mklement0, I trust the copious comments on the various answers to this question to clarify the ambiguities.